# zsh: command not found: tmuxinator

Tags: vagrant, zsh, tmuxinator

Using vagrant/zsh. Installed `tmuxinator`

```
➜  ~ gem list tmuxinator
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
tmuxinator (0.9.0)
```

Set completion

```
➜  ~ ls ~/.bin
tmuxinator.zsh
```

.zshrc

```
...
source ~/.bin/tmuxinator.zsh
```

But when run `tmuxinator`

```
➜  ~ tmuxinator
zsh: command not found: tmuxinator
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `tmuxinator doctor` to check if everything properly installed and setup.

I installed on a fresh vagrant ubuntu box the tmuxinator. I had to export my editor and shell variables. I ran tmuxinator doctor which told me everything was fine:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 ~ ❯❯❯ tmuxinator doctor                                                    ⏎
Checking if tmux is installed ==> Yes
Checking if $EDITOR is set ==> Yes
Checking if $SHELL is set ==> Yes
```

I didn't have to fuss with tmuninator.zsh to start it. Note the exe is located in:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 ~ ❯❯❯ which -a tmuxinator                                                  ⏎
/usr/local/bin/tmuxinator
```